# Downloading S3 file gives date parsing error for Pacific Standard Time zone

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am trying to download a "csv.gz" file from S3 bucket using aws java SDK.

```
    AWSCredentials credentails = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    AmazonS3 s3Connection = new AmazonS3Client(credentails);
    S3Object s3object = connection.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(
                        bucketName, filename));
```

I am getting the following date format error while using S3Connection.getObject() method.

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3MetadataResponseHandler populateObjectMetadata
WARNING: Unable to parse http expiration date: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 16:00:00 PST
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Wed, 31 Dec 1969 16:00:00 PST" is malformed at " PST"
  at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.doParseMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:187)
  at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseMillis(DateTimeFormatter.java:780)
  at com.amazonaws.util.DateUtils.parseRFC822Date(DateUtils.java:196)
  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.AbstractS3ResponseHandler.populateObjectMetadata(AbstractS3ResponseHandler.java:136)
  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3ObjectResponseHandler.handle(S3ObjectResponseHandler.java:51)
  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3ObjectResponseHandler.handle(S3ObjectResponseHandler.java:30)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1179)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:820)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:630)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:405)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:367)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:318)
  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3787)
  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1137)
```

can someone please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance,

Senthil